# How to change the structure of a pd DataFrame adding row values to columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following data frame

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['2020-01-01', '2020-10-01', '2021-01-01', '2021-10-01'],
                   'ID': [101, 101, 102, 102],
                   'number': [10, 10, 11, 11]})

# currently looking like this

    Date        ID  number
0   2020-01-01  101 10
1   2020-10-01  101 10
2   2021-01-01  102 11
3   2021-10-01  102 11
```

Is there a way to restructure the data frame in such a way to have the following form?

```
    Start Date  End Date    ID  number
0   2020-01-01  2020-10-01  101 10
1   2021-01-01  2021-10-01  102 11
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use [Named Aggregation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/groupby.html#named-aggregation) with [Groupby aggregate](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html) to get the `min` and `max` Date per group and set with new names. [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) is optional to reorder columns to match shown expected output:

```
new_df = df.groupby(
    ['ID', 'number'], as_index=False
).aggregate(
    **{'Start Date': ('Date', 'min'), 'End Date': ('Date', 'max')}
).reindex(columns=['Start Date', 'End Date', 'ID', 'number'])
```

`new_df`:

```
   Start Date    End Date   ID  number
0  2020-01-01  2020-10-01  101      10
1  2021-01-01  2021-10-01  102      11
```

*Dictionary unpacking `**` is needed to allow for renamed columns to have spaces.

Comment: Nice answer. How would it be simpler if there are no required spaces in renamed columns?

Comment: @zabop `.aggregate(start_date=('Date', 'min'), end_date=('Date', 'max'))` would work rather than creating a dictionary and unpacking.